# Definition of simple curve using index or intersection.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In complex analysis, as an example in Sarasson's book, we define simple contour with index of curve as our main tool. I have also seen in many, undergraduate, books of the same topic that they define simple closed curve, as a continuous injective function for all points except the extremes on the defined interval.
My question is how these two definitions are related, more particular, why the fact of a curve not having any intersection in complex plane implies that its index equals to only 1 or 0.

Comment: The fact that a continuous injective map $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defines a curve such that the index of any point not in the curve is $0$ or $\pm 1$ (and that exactly two possibilities appear, one per connected component of $\mathbb{C} \backslash f(S^1)$, so that zero always appear) is (I think) the Jordan Curve Theorem, which is definitely nontrivial.

Comment: note that the index is not enough-- you should be able to come up with a curve whose image looks like an $8$ and has winding number of $1$ or $0$ for all points in its complement but the curve's complement has 3 components, not 2, and hence is not homeomorphic to a simple path around the unit circle (Jordan Curve Theorem).